# Finding imagemap areas using Capybara

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

Using Capybara, I would like to simulate a click on the area within an image that is defined by an imagemap's `area` element. Using `.find` with or without `visible: true` on the class/id attributes of that specific element isn't working - I get either a `Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode` error, or a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error. Instead if I simply trigger it via Javascript, like so, then my tests do pass:

```
page.execute_script('$(".ClassSelector").trigger("click")')
```

So the page is working like it should, but I'd like to know if I can avoid `execute_script` in writing my tests.

I am using `capybara` 2.5 and `poltergeist` 1.7

Comment: From a quick test I would say Poltergeist doesn't work with imagemaps.  Might be worth filing an issue on the project.

Comment: If you write an answer comparing Poltergeist to Selenium and/or Webkit to address this, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. I might get around to it myself later...

Comment: @sameers, check whether the element is in iframe!!!

Comment: I just merged support for clicking on the area element of an image map into the master branch of poltergeist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current poltergeist doesn't seem to work with image maps (I'll look at fixing that this weekend), and will return an error stating that a different element would be clicked.  Selenium does work correctly with the image map so you could have those specs that require image maps run with selenium.

Update - I merged support for clicking on an area element of an image map into poltergeist master branch on Jan 24th, 2016 -- It should be in the next release